# Align borders by CSS with nested divs

Tags: css, box-sizing

I have the layout in https://jsfiddle.net/Ld07e4s7/4/ but I'm unable to make the first blue-border go to the same extent as the others blue-borders.

```css
div.table
{
 width: 100%;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-column
{
 float: left;
}

div.table > div.header > div
{
 height: calc(1.5em);
 /*display: flex;
 align-items: center;*/
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}

div.table > div.header div
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-row > .grid-column
{
 border-top: solid red 5px;
}

div.table > div.header > .grid-row > .grid-column
{
 border-left: solid blue 5px;
}

div.table > div.header > .grid-row > .grid-column .grid-column:nth-child(n+2)
{
 border-left: solid yellow 5px;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-column
{
 background-color: lightgreen;
 /*border: solid red 5px;*/
 /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}

div.table > div.header .grid-row
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.prensaGrid > div.header > div.grid-column
{
 height: calc(1.5em * 6);
}

.prensaGrid > div.header > div.grid-row > div.grid-column:nth-child(1)
{
 width: calc(100% / 17);
}

.prensaGrid > div.header > div.grid-row > div.grid-column:nth-child(n+2)
{
 width: calc(100% / 17 * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="table prensaGrid">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="grid-row">
   <div class="grid-column" style="height: calc(1.5em * 6)">Amostras</div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Diâmetro Externo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     Profundidade Rebaixo<br />(mm)
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Mín.
     </div>
     <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 3)">
      Máx.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div style="float: none; clear: both"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="float: none; clear: both"></div>
 </div>
 <div style="float: none; clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div style="float: none; clear: both"></div>
```

Maybe I do not understand well the box-sizing. But without it it brokens even more:

```
div.table > div.header div
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also this layout brokes in Edge. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you add your markup

Comment: Dear God, use `<table>`...

Comment: @AndréDion the real layout is very complex. I was using, but then I need to change the tbody display to make a scrollbar around only the tbody, and that brokes everything when I need to use rowspan/colspan.

Comment: I can't comment on what problems you were having with your use of `<table>`, but this looks like a prime example of when you should be using tables to present tabular data.

Comment: @AndréDionno problem if you show me a table that works with the fixed header in the screen with scrollbars only in the body and that works with rowspan/colspan and settable widths with things like calc(100% / n).

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `box-sizing: border-box`, you need to add the border size:

```
height: calc(1.5em * 6 + 5px);
```

You could use `box-sizing: content-box` but then you would have horizontal problems.

Comment: I understand the thing about adding to the margin, but with border-box I understand that would not be necessary as the others box heights would be the same as without borders. No?

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes `.grid-row` are `1.5em * 3` tall, with no border. So the outer height of the `.grid-column` with two `.grid-row`and a 5px top border is `1.5em * 6 + 5px`. Your first element has `height: calc(1.5em * 6)`, so with `box-sizing: border-box` its outer height is `height: calc(1.5em * 6)`.

Comment: "So the outer height of the .grid-column with two .grid-rowand a 5px top border is 1.5em * 6 + 5px" -> @Oriol All the divs has "box-sizing: border-box;", so they heights should not be "+ 5px". If you change the red border to 15px, you clear see only the top row increases its height, but the bottom one (using the same style) does not. Why that happen?

Comment: You set the border to .grid-column which has auto height. Of course the border won't be subtracted from the height contribution of the children, otherwise they would overflow. So you get +5px. Consider setting theborder to the .grid-row instead

Answer (score 0):

I now achieve what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/mozf1uLk/

I do not understand why in the first example the group in the first row changed its height even with border-box.

Here is the version working:

```
<div class="table prensaGrid">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="grid-column" style="height: calc(1.5em * 8)">1</div>

            <div class="grid-column-group">
                <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 4)">
                    <div class="grid-column" style="width: 100%; height: calc(1.5em * 4)">
                        2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-row" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 4)">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-column" style="width: 50%; height: calc(1.5em * 4)">
                        4
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="float: none; clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
div.table
{
    width: 100%;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-column,
div.table > div.header .grid-column-group
{
    float: left;
}

div.table > div.header div
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-row/*:not(:last-child)*/
{
    border-bottom: solid red 5px;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-column
{
    border-top: solid red 5px;
}

div.table > div.header > .grid-row .grid-column
{
    border-left: solid red 5px;
}

div.table > div.header > .grid-row .grid-column:last-child
{
    border-right: solid red 5px;
}

div.table > div.header .grid-column
{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.prensaGrid > div.header > div.grid-row > div.grid-column:nth-child(1)
{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.prensaGrid > div.header > div.grid-row > div.grid-column-group:nth-child(n+2)
{
    width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
}
```